# To use DefWindowProc or not to use DefWindowProc

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently writing my own mini visual framework to wrap pure WinAPI in classes.

Currently the process of analyzing messages looks as follows:

- static `Application::Run` has a message loop; it gets new message and dispatches it to apropriate WndProc.
- All windows I create are created from the same class (in terms of WinAPI), so the same `WndProc` is being called. Actually, it's a static `FormAPI::WndProc` method. This one checks, which window the message refers to and calls its `WndProc`.
- `Form::WndProc` method is called, which analyzes message. Suppose, that it's a `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. It calls `ProcessMouseMove` and then `DefWindowProc`. Remember this point as [1].
- private `Form::ProcessMouseMove` gets the actual data from the message (eg. x, y, shift state), converts it into usable data and calls protected `Form::OnMouseMove`.
- Finally, protected `OnMouseMove` checks, whether event handler is set (that is, `std::function<void(Form *, int, int, ShiftState)>` ) and if so, it calls the handler. Otherwise it does nothing.

My concern is about calling `DefWindowProc`. It may seem, that its simply "do the default behavior for me", but sometimes it actually does some critical stuff. For instance, disabling `WM_LBTNDOWN` by not calling `DefWindowProc` will result in inability to close window by clicking the [X] button.

On the other hand, sometimes I don't want to call `DefWindowProc`. For instance, if `WM_CLOSE` comes, I may decide not to close application. `DefWindowProc` in this case calls `DestroyWindow`.

My question is: should I call the `DefWindowProc` or not? If so, always or only sometimes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've got *three* choices when deciding how to handle a message:

- Not calling DefWindowProc().  Appropriate when you want to completely customize the way the message is handled and do not want the default implementation.  WM_COMMAND and WM_PAINT are typical examples.
- Do something custom, then calling DefWindowProc().  Appropriate when you like or need the default implementation.  WM_CLOSE is a typical example.
- First call DefWindowProc(), then altering the result if appropriate.  A typical example is WM_NCHITTEST

There is no golden rule to select the appropriate choice,  it depends a great deal on the specific message and the specific default handling for the window.  Note that this may not be the documented default handling if you are subclassing a window.  Getting it wrong is however generally easy to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that I've answered my question simply by asking it. I presented two cases:

- `WM_LBTNDOWN` when `DefWindowProc` *has* to be called - otherwise window won't work properly;
- `WM_CLOSE`, when - depending on event handler - `DefWindowProc` *must not* be called - otherwise it'll break the framework's logic.

The answer is then: it depends on kind of message. I have to read carefully, how DefWindowProc works in every case and act appropriately.

Comment: It comes down to "has it been handled or not". My window handle wrapper has a handled flag, which when set to true, causes it to exit rather than call `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: That depends, again. If you use `handled` in - say - `WM_LBTNDOWN`, you give an opportunity to event handler to lock user from closing window. In other words, event handler has to be responsible for deciding, whether to call `DefWindowProc` or not. It is doable, but I wouldn't call that comfortable... unless I misunderstood your concept.

Comment: Well, the event handler is specific to every message. By default, it should be called, but then the handle can block this if required. I assume you also have specific code in your library for each message so you can override this if a certain message never needs to be passed.

Comment: I consider it should always be called unless you want to specifically prevent the default behavior. Which is basically what you already said.